# Spark Structured Streaming - read/write from/to DynamoDB

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-dynamodb, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I have an use case that should read from kafka and DynamoDB sources and then write to an hive table and also update one or more DynamoDB tables.

We are using spark structured streaming. Some questions:

1. How to read from DynamoDB "format"? More specifically, how to do **spark.readStream.format("kafka").load()** but using Dynamo? I read about Kinesis also, don't know if it can be a solution.
2. How to write to Dynamo? We are writing using the forEachBatch for a hive table what leads me to think that we can call the API from this framework https://github.com/audienceproject/spark-dynamodb in order to do the writing.

Basically, I need some hints and best pratices in order to read and write from DynamoDB using spark structured streaming. Anything usefull, please share.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kinesis-integration.html and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.KCLAdapter.html

Comment: This is for reading, right? For writing what does you recommend?